# Develop a table of strings in a two-dimensional table

Tags: c

I have this exercise that i can't understand and i hoped somebody could help me with it.

Develop a function that receives a table of strings, each one
with a maximum of 40 characters, and return the index of the largest of them. Note: The function receives a two-dimensional table, with the first dimension of the table not specified.

My question is how do i use the two dimensional table in this exercise i normally only used the a normal array to do strings, and after that what is exactly the index of a string? Is its lenght? Because if it is i know how to do the problem using the function strlen. I just dont understand how the table will work. If somebody can please help me (sorry for my bad english).

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYGwk.png)

Answer (score 1):

This means, your function should work like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int func (char table[][40], int numentries) {
    ...
}

int main (void) {
    int index;
    char example[][40] = {
        "this",
        "is",
        "an",
        "example",
        "with",
        "seven",
        "words"
    };

    index = func(example, 7);
    printf("The longest word has index %d\n", index);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

(maybe it should even be 41 instead of 40 to have space for the zero-byte, depending if this is already counted in or not in the specification)

Now, each entry of the table has at most 40 characters, but the number of entries is unspecified and has to be passed in a separate argument.
You can iterate over the table from `i = 0` up to numentries and find the element with the greatest length. The corresponding `i` is the index you have to return.

Comment: Oh oh thanks i will start right away ant thanks for the quick answer

Comment: May also be written with `int func (char (*table)[40], ...` since when passed as a parameter the first level of indirection is converted to a pointer. (both are equally correct)

Comment: i still have a problem when i try to compile i get an error because of a missing array size in variable table

Comment: @FabianPereira Can you show the code please? (edit your question)

Comment: @FabianPereira The syntax `char table[][40]` is only valid as a parameter or with a static initializer. The assignment says, you should develop a function. I gave you the prototype, you "just" have to fill in the logic. I will further give you example code to test your function now.

Comment: i still can't do the function if it's not much to ask can you show how you would do the function, and that the programa asks how many strings the user wants to type

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, make sure you understand what was done- if something is unclear- ask. I hope this helps:

Note that if there are multiple max the index returned will be for the first string of that length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetLongestString(char sArr[][40], int row)
{
   int i = 0;
   int max = 0;
   int maxindex = -1; 
   for(i= 0 ; i< row; ++i) /*to check each row*/
   {
       if(max < strlen(&sArr[i][0])) /*gives the add of each rows string beginning for 
                                                                          the strlen function */
       {
          max = strlen(&sArr[i][0]);/*get the max value and store it for later 
                                                                        checks*/
          maxindex = i;/* save the index of max length*/
       }
   }

 return maxindex;
}

int main()
{
  int res = 0;
  char array[2][40] ={"all", "hello"};
  char array2[2][40] ={"hello", "all"};

  res = GetLongestString(array,2);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  res = GetLongestString(array2,2);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

Good luck!